# Excel VBA using Variable in Workbook Active is not working (getting active workbook name dynamically)

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guy i am creating vba project where i need to switch from one workbook to another where i need dynamic active workbook name

so i am trying to use this code, here i am getting error **"script out of range"**

```
Dim wb
wb = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
wb = Split(wb, "\")(UBound(Split(wb, "\")))
Workbooks("wb").Activate
```

but when i am changing dynamic name of active workbook to static.. this code works...

```
Dim wb
Workbooks("project1.xlsm").Activate
```

please help guys.. cause i need dynamic name of active workbook...

Comment: Why don't you do `Dim wb As Workbook` `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` and then just use `wb` to refer to the workbook without having to `Activate` it?

Comment: (But if you **have** to have the name, just use `wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name`, and then refer to the workbook using `Workbooks(wb)`.)

Comment: @YowE3K updated my code with Dim wb as Workbook, now error is "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: and if i use wb=activeworkbook.name then i will get only workbook name without extension but to use "workbooks("wb") active", it should have workbook name with extension

Comment: You will need to show the code you are now using before we can guess as to what is wrong.  (I assume the error is on one of the lines you changed to use the `wb` object - is that right?)

Comment: What makes you think that `ActiveWorkbook.Name` will drop off the extension?  (And don't put variable names within double-quotation marks - double-quotation marks in VBA are used to signify string literals - it should be `Workbooks(wb)` if the variable `wb` is the `Name` of the workbook being referred to, and it would be `Workbooks("wb")` only if `"wb"` was the actual workbook name, e.g. `Workbooks("Book1")` is the default workbook when you first create a new workbook.)

Comment: @YowE3K thanks brother... it is working now... it was silly mistake that i was using double quotation on variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error in your existing code is caused by you trying to use the `String` literal `"wb"` instead of the variable `wb`.  So the following should work:

```
Dim wb As String
wb = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
wb = Split(wb, "\")(UBound(Split(wb, "\")))
Workbooks(wb).Activate
```

However, using the `FullName` and then stripping off the path component is no different to using the `Name` property:

```
Dim wb As String
wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(wb).Activate
```

But it would be better to just create a `Workbook` object and use it directly:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Activate
```

---

Note:  There are very few occasions when the use of `Activate` and `Select` is necessary.  Without seeing your following code it is hard to help you with good code, but maybe it is something like:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

It may be an idea to check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336).